# How to stop Pyrebase set() from overriding existing data?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I am creating a simple directory with Flask & Pyrebase; I have managed to create the login ok, and the registration form.  The user is redirected to their profile page once signed in & registered.

My issue that I have is when I try to add a new entry my existing data is overwritten. When I create a new db entry I use set() instead of push() I am thinking this could be why?

I have shortened the code us much as possible

creating account & registering business:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
unsuccessful = 'Please check your credentials'
successful = 'Registraion successful'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        confirmEmail = request.form('confirmEmail')
        password = request.form.get('pass')
        userName = request.form.get('inputName')
        businessName = request.form.get('businessName')
        startYear = request.form.get('startYear')
        selectCategory = request.form.get('selectCategory')
        businessDescription = request.form.get('businessDescription')
        businessAddress = request.form.get('businessAddress')
        businessTown = request.form.get('businessTown')
        businessCity = request.form.get('businessCity')
        businessPostcode = request.form.get('businessPostcode')
        businessNumber = request.form.get('businessNumber')
        businessEmail = request.form.get('businessEmail')
        bameRegister = dict(
            userName = userName,
            confirmationEmail = confirmEmail,
            businessName = businessName,
            businessStartYear = startYear,
            businessCategory = selectCategory,
            businessDescription = businessDescription,
            businessAddress = [businessAddress, businessTown, businessCity, businessPostcode],
            businessNumber = businessNumber,
            businessEmail = businessEmail,
        )
        if selectCategory == "arts":
            try:
                user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
                auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
                db.child("Bame_Buisness").child("business").child("arts").set(bameRegister, user['idToken'])
                return render_template('homepage.html', x=successful)
            except:
                return render_template('homepage.html', y=unsuccessful)
        elif selectCategory == "food":
            try:
                user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
                auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
                db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("food").set(bameRegister, user['idToken'])
                return render_template('homepage.html', x=successful)
            except:
                return render_template('homepage.html', y=unsuccessful)
       elif selectCategory == "health":
           try:
               user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
               auth.send_email_verification(user['idToken'])
               db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("health").set(bameRegister, user['idToken'])
               return render_template('homepage.html', x=successful)
            except:
               return render_template('homepage.html', y=unsuccessful)
    return render_template('homepage.html')
```

Creating the login:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    unsuccessful = 'Please check your credentials'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            signed_in_user = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])
            artCategory = db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("arts").get(user['idToken']).val()
            foodCategory = db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("food").get(user['idToken']).val()
            healthCategory = db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("health").get(user['idToken']).val()
            if signed_in_user['users'][0]['email'] == artCategory['confirmationEmail']:
                return render_template('profile.html', artCategory=artCategory)
            elif signed_in_user['users'][0]['email'] == foodCategory['confirmationEmail']:
                return render_template('profile.html', foodCategory=foodCategory)
            elif signed_in_user['users'][0]['email'] == healthCategory['confirmationEmail']:
                return render_template('profile.html', healthCategory=heathCategory)
        except:
            return render_template('homepage.html')
    return render_template('homepage.html')
```

This is the route to create a new business once logged in:

```
@app.route('newBusiness', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newBusiness():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        confirmEmail = request.form.get('confirmEmail')
        password = request.form.get('pass')
        userName = request.form.get('userName')
        businessName = request.form.get('businessName')
        startYear = request.form.get('startYear')
        selectCategory = request.form.get('selectCategory')
        businessDescription = request.form.get('businessDescription')
        businessAddress = request.form.get('businessAddress')
        businessTown = request.form.get('businessTown')
        businessCity = request.form.get('businessCity')
        businessPostcode = request.get('businessPostcode')
        businessNumber = request.form.get('businessNumber')
        businessEmail = request.form.get('businessEmail')
        bameRegister = dict(
            userName = userName,
            confirmationEmail = confirmEmail,
            businessName = businessName,
            businessStartYear = startYear,
            businessCategory = businessCategory,
            businessDescription = businessDescription,
            businessAddress = [businessAddress, businessTown, businessCity, businessPostcode],
            businessNumber = businessNumber,
            businessEmail = businessEmail,
        )
        if selectCategory == "arts":
            try:
                user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
                user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
                db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("arts").set(bameRegister, user['idToken'])
                signed_in_user = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])
                artCategory = db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("arts").get(user['idToken']).val()
                if signed_in_user['users'][0]['email'] == artCategory['confirmationEmail']:
                   return render_template('profile.html', artCategory=artCategory)
            except:
                return render_template('homepage.html')
        elif selectCategory == "food":
            try:
                user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
                user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
                db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("food").set(bameRegister, user['idToken'])
                signed_in_user = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])
                foodCategory = db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("food").get(user['idToken']).val()
                if signed_in_user['users'][0]['email'] == foodCategory['confirmationEmail']:
                    return render_template('profile.html', foodCategory=foodCategory)
            except:
                return render_template('homepage.html')
        elif selectCategory == "health":
            try:
                user = auth.sign_in_with_emal_and_password(email, password)
                user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
                db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("health").set(bameRegister, user['idToken'])
                signed_in_user = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])
                healthCategory = db.child("Bame_Business").child("business").child("health").get(user['idToken']).val()
                if signed_in_user['users'][0]['email'] == healthCategory['confirmationEmail']:
                    return render_template('profile.html', healthCategory=healthCategory)
            except:
                return render_template('homepage.html')
    return render_template('homepage.html')
```

After the user has logged in, lets say they register their 1st business in the arts category, when they register their 2nd different business in the arts category the original collection is overwritten in Firebase.  This happens even when selecting a different category.  This is definitely not ideal as someone could overwrite someone else's data - which then leads to all sorts of problems!

I understand you can use push & set to create new entries in pyrebase; I chose set because when I used push it creates a unique tag which I found it hard to get individual access from a users account.  With the set method it is easy to call out the part of the dictionary I want with `artCategory['businessName']` or `artCategory['businessDescription']` or `artCategory['confirmationEmail']` etc

I just need to create a new business registration after login in without overriding any existing data, if anyone could help me come up with a solution that would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

`.set()` overrides.  `.update()` updates only the fields that have changed.

Comment: so then I have to use ```.push()```?